# Downloading Generated Document

Tags: docusignapi

We're trying to use Docusign for a simple letter generation type process, replacing parameters in a template with provided data.  Rather than emailing the generated document out to the recipient, we want to download the generated document.

Using the REST API, I can generate an emailed version, or download a copy of the template.  But I don't seem to be able to download a copy of the generated document without it being emailed to the recipient.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see API call [EnvelopeDocuments:get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get)

It enable you to download either the complete set of documents in an envelope or a specific doc.

Code example of using it are available for multiple languages:

- [Listing an envelope's documents](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-list-envelope-documents)
- [Downloading an envelope's documents](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-download-envelope-documents)

Comment: Thanks @Larry K.  Those calls are what we've been trying to use.  The downloaded document doesn't have the recipient data merged into it.  It is fine if it's emailed to the recipient.  Any ideas if I could be missing anything else?

Comment: Are you downloading after the envelope has been completed (completely signed)?

Comment: For this, a signature isn't required.  Running through the process of viewing the document and then downloading from the completed envelope gives the merged document as expected.  We may be able to tweak the end to end process in some way if the envelope needs to be completed to get this working.

Comment: Are there any recipients for the document? If not, try waiting until the document reaches the "completed" state. If that doesn't work, add a cc recipient with a black hole email address.